# HERE-API How to configure the poi filter when requesting map tiles

Tags: here-api

I would like to filter the POIs added to my map tiles to some category but I don't understand how to move from the POI categories available in the meta-data to the hexadecimal filter. The example provided in the developer documentation is too simple.

For example if I want to have only city halls (category 323), which value should I put for the pois attribute of my request?

And if I want to combine it with Fire Departments (category 246)?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hexadecimal value for city halls (category 323) is 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001.

For Fire Department (category 246) it is 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002.

You can use the map table (provided in the [link](https://hmcs-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/monal_shah_here_com/EVXmZ82f5zJJlCIJV77KE6cBE6RCIequWfvyg5WEsLZYPw?e=KbPakp)) in your program code or you can calculate the HEX values in runtime utilize this code snippet:

```
 // 1. get poi categories /meta/pois?output=json and store them in a list
  // 2. create a list with inputs of type checkbox
 // 3. create a 'change' listener that includes the following logic
     var bit, bits = '0', hex = '', n=1;
 // please pay attention as the index starts on '1' as the
 // first bit is always initialized to '0' because it is a reserved bit
     $('.poi').each(function {
     bit = $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0';
     bits = bits + bit;
     if ((n+1)%4 == 0)
{               hex = hex + parseInt(bits, 2).toString(16); bits = '';         }

    n = n + 1
   });
   if (bits !== '') hex = hex + parseInt(bits, 2).toString(16);
   // we remove the trailing zeroes as they are not needed
       hex = hex.replace(/0+$/g, '');
   // trigger a map update using the parameter &pois=hex
```

Comment: Thank you for this complete and precise reply. It is exactly what I was looking for.